# Property 'NUM' is missing in type 'ListePrea' but required in type 'Toto'

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to retrieve data from a web service.

I have an error message:

> Property 'NUM' is missing in type 'ListePrea' but required in type 'Toto'.

[image]

Sincerely, I don't understand the problem, I'm still a beginner in Angular.

1. Here is the JSON structure

[image]

2. toto.service.ts

The service interacts with the backend. [No Problem]

```
@Injectable()
export class TotoService {
    private readonly api: string = environment.api;
    num: string | null = null;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private datePipe: CphFormatDatePipe) {}

    getTransferDetails(num: string): Observable < TotoResponse > {
        return this.http.post < TotoResponse > (this.api + `/WAMCHOM`, {
            NUM: parseInt(num)

        }, );
    }

}
```

3. toto.response.ts

I feel like it's not correct to use a class?  [There is a problem?]

```
export interface TotoResponse extends ApiResponse {

    PREA: ListePrea;
}

export interface ListePrea {
    PREA: {
        CLER: string;
        NUM: number;
        REF_RBC: string;
        TYPE: string;
        QUANTITE: number;
        ISIN: string;
        TRADE_DATE: Date;
        RECEPTION_DATE: Date;
        STATUT: number;
        LABEL: string;
        SVM: number;
        COURS_MOYEN_ACHAT: number;
        PERSONNE_CONTACT: string;
        TEL: number;
        FAX: number;
        DATE: Date;
        TRAITEMENT_DATE: Date;
        ANNULATION_DATE: Date;
        INTITULE1: string;
        CONTREPARTIE: string;      
        TIS: number;
        CHANGEMENT_BENEF_ECO: string;
        REM1: string;
        REM2: string;
    };
}


export class Toto {
    NUM: number | null = null;

    constructor(
        NUM: number | null = null,
    ) {
        this.NUM = NUM;
    }
}
```

4. toto.component.ts

I don't understand why the line `this.listPreas = res.PREA;` is wrong? [Problem]

```
export class TotoComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {


    private unsubscribe$ = new Subject < void > ();
    num: string | null = null;

    listPreas: Toto = new Toto(parseInt(this.num + ''));


    constructor(
        private service: TotoService,
        private createDateTimePipe: CreateDateTimePipe,
        private location: Location,
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.num = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('num');

        if (!this.num) {
            this.goBack();
            return;
        }
        this.getTransferDetails();
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.unsubscribe$.next();
        this.unsubscribe$.complete();
    }

    private getTransferDetails(): void {
        this.service.getTransferDetails(this.num!).pipe(
            takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
        ).subscribe(res => {
            if (res.RETURNCODE === ApiResponseCodeEnum.Ok) {
                this.listPreas = res.PREA;
            }
        });
    }

    goBack(): void {
        this.location.back();
    }

}
```

Thank you very much for your help, I really want to understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `Toto` instance and get the value from `res.PREA.PREA.NUM`

```js
this.listPreas = new Toto(res.PREA.PREA.NUM);
```

```js
private getTransferDetails(): void {
    this.service.getTransferDetails(this.num!).pipe(
        takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
    ).subscribe(res => {
        if (res.RETURNCODE === ApiResponseCodeEnum.Ok) {
            this.listPreas = new Toto(res.PREA.PREA.NUM);
        }
    });
}
```

Note that based on `TotoResponse` and `ListePrea`, your JSON should be something as:

```
{
    PREA: {
        PREA: {
            CLER: "",
            NUM: 1,
            // Following properties
        }
    }
}
```

There is nested level with property name `PREA`